# ECS container debugging process

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, containers, amazon-ecs, identity-management

How can I access my ECS container task if it is terminated with a successful event for the debugging process to ensure my logs are available?

As of now, I am able to go inside my container with the ecs-exec command whenever a new task is created to check the logs, and the container is in a running state.

My question is: if a container is terminated with a successful event, how can I access that particular container to view the logs?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access my ECS container task if it is terminated

Once a container is terminated, it doesn't exist anymore. You can't access it at that point. This is like asking how you can use your computer when it is turned off.

You should configure your ECS tasks to [log to AWS CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-logging-monitoring.html). Then you will be able to view the logs in CloudWatch without needing to access the container.

Answer (score 0):

For a terminated container, you would need to store the logs in either AWS Native logging solution eg [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) wherein you would use `awslog` driver in your ECS task definition or you use a 3rd party logging solution wherein you can use [AWS FireLens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_firelens.html) to push logs to 3rd party logstorage system. `Firelens` would also make sense if you want to ship to `CloudWatch` and perform upfront filtering